# Confusion matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to understand this piece of information, and im confused on this.

```
    a  b  c  <-- classified as
    11 1  1  | a = 1
    2  11 0  | b = 2
    0  0  13 | c = 3
```

Comment: We are just as confused. Can you ask a question?

Comment: I need to understand this confusion matrix, which has been implemented on Weka.

Comment: What do you not understand? Did you try googling? Did you look at the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)?

Comment: I did. just cant figure it out. On how the whole confusion matrix works.

Comment: What values are you attempting to calculate from this matrix? Can you post your attempts?